# Text Segmentation Dataset

Tags: dataset, text-segmentation

I wonder if someone can help me to get a dataset to test Text Segmentation approach that I developed and want to test.

I looked for Freddy Choi's dataset and I couldn't find it. I need this dataset specifically.

If someone has it or knows where I can get it, please advice.

Also if anyone has suggestions for other datasets for the same task, please advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Freddy Choi seems to have disappeared, but I've imported his source code and data to some GitHub repositories:

- [C99](https://github.com/logological/C99) (versions 1.0, 1.1, and 1.2)
- [C99 Demo](https://github.com/logological/C99demo) (version 1.0)

Answer (score 1):

I found it. It was somehow tricky, but I found it.
this link has Choi's software and datasets.
I found Choi's page on web.archive.org

http://web.archive.org/web/20040810103924/http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~mary/choif/software.html